# Filtering out content with style display:none in an XPath expression

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to parse with lxml in python and this is my output

```
<td>
    <span style="display:inline">text1</span>
    <span style="display:none">text2</span>
    <span>text3</span>
    text4
</td>
```

Thought I was smart enough to use the following

```
tree = tr.xpath("//*[contains(@style,'inline')]/text()")
```

But then I thought I would only see text1. 
What I want is to see text3 and text4 too so that the output will be

['text1', 'text3', 'text4']

Can anyone send me to the right direction of doing it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Explicitly exclude anything with `display:none`:

```
tree = tr.xpath("//*[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]/text()")
```

That said -- this is only a distant approximation of what a browser would actually do; you'd want to be driving an actual browser (as with Selenium, embedding APIs, or the like) if you required strictly accurate results.

Comment: If it is written in DOM with a space, like "display: none", then it won't work.